# Stretching fabric

Tags: objects, cloth-simulation

I'm quite a beginner in this, but I've been using blender for quite some time now for my artwork (2d paintings). I was attempting to achieve an effect of an object sitting on top of a fabric in a way that stretches it. (like in the picture below- so the little stones stretching the fabric) so far unsuccessfully. Anyone have an idea of how to go about it? Thanks in advance!!
[image]

Comment: Paul Gonet's answer is a pretty good one, however it can become computationally expensive. If you are planning on animating it, it is most definitely the way to go, however if you are not, I would imagine that sculpting the verts/edges either with proportional editing, or possibly just using the scuplting tools would be a better fit.

Comment: Hey Rick! I do not intend to animate it, i'm only interested in getting a high res image. your idea worked brilliantly. I'm a novice at this so I did not even consider sculpt mode but went straight for cloth simulation which I normally use. It does require a bit of practicing and I find it to be less compelling than what the cloth simulation achieves, but for now it is sufficient for what I need. so thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Although I guess you may achieve it animating *shape keys*, while running the *cloth simulation* I think there is an easier method that fakes it.
[image]

Add a *plane* and model the pattern of the stretches. Add a *Subsurf Modifier* to it and *smooth* it. Enable the ***Collision*** physics for it. It'll be the ground. 
[image]
[image]

Now create a new *plane* (it'll be the fabric) and subdivide it few times with <kbd>W</kbd>-->*Subdivide*. Apply transformations to it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>). Use *shape keys* to stretch it (use proportional editing for mesh editing). Add a *Subsurf Modifier* to your fabric, enable ***Cloth*** physics.

***EDIT:*** You don't need to use *shape keys* for this- just transform the fabric's corners (<kbd>G</kbd>), though *shape keys* give you ability to experiment with the final fabric shape, as you may tweak it very fast.
[image]
[image]

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to run a *simulation*. Then pause it, apply the *shape keys* and *Cloth Modifier*.
[image]